# Header - Forwarding variables via PHP to pages without $_GET

Tags: php

I have one page A having this code snippet

```
if (!var) {
  header("Location: ".URL, true, 301);
  exit();
}

if (!var2) {
  header("Location: ". $url2, true, 301);
  exit();
}
```

I want to create a page in between URL/$url2 and A I call this one B.

How do I have to change A to give B the content of URL/$url2 without the user seeing it? I could use something like

```
Location: mypage.php?url=$url2
```

But the user could change that what I don't want. If you recommend $_POST how would you do it? If not, what would you do?

I changed it to

```
session_start();
if (!var) {
  //header("Location: ".URL, true, 301);
  $data = URL;
  $_SESSION['keks'] = $data;
  require("transition.php");
  exit();
}
```

transition.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Frameset</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="50%,50%">
  <frame src="above.php" name="Navigation">
  <frame src="http://www.domain.com" name="Daten">
  <noframes>
    <body>
      <p>Something</p>
    </body>
  </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

above.php:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="text-align: right;"><a href="<?php echo $_SESSION['keks']; ?>">Continue</a> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which leads to

```
<a href="">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a session cookie.

On the page with the info you can save text etc into a session var like this:

```
$data = 'hello';
$_SESSION['xxx'] = $data;
```

And get it back on the next page like this:

```
echo $_SESSION['xxx'];
// Hello
```

Dont forget you need to run `session_start();` before using sessions.

Comment: It seems to get lost on the way. I changed it like this here -> see answer your question.

Comment: You can debug it by making a page with just `print_r($_SESSION);` and refresh it to see what the current session vars are.